# PHP Warning: oci_fetch_array() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

Tags: php, oracle, mode, oracle-call-interface

I'm trying to define a `function` to execute an Oracle query and set the mode for `oci_fetch_array()` dynamically with the `string` variable received. This is the function:

```
public function db_single_select($conn,$select,$table,$condition,$fetch_mods='') {

    //A string should be sent to "$fetch_mods" with this format: mode1+mode2+etc...  
    //If a value is not passed to '$fetch_mods', it will be the default fetch mode

    $sql = oci_parse($conn, "select $select from $table where $condition");
    $sql_result = oci_execute($sql, OCI_DEFAULT); 
    if($sql_result){
        if(empty($fetch_mods)) {                    
            $res = oci_fetch_array($sql);
        }
        else{
            $res = oci_fetch_array($sql, $fetch_mods);
        }                   
    }
    else{
        $res = FALSE;
    }               
    oci_free_statement($sql);
    return $res;
}
```

I call the function like this:

`db_single_select($conn, $select, $table_name, $condition, 'OCI_ASSOC');`

I get this Warning:

`Warning: oci_fetch_array() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in db_connect.php on line 61`

I know that the second parameter (mode) for `oci_fetch_array()` should be numeric as it says so in the PHP documentation. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-array.php

The question is how to set the mode based on a variable received by the function??

Since you can have multiple modes by seperating them with a `+` sign like

`$row = oci_fetch_array ($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS);`

, is there an easy way to receive a string like `OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS` in the function and set the mode with that??

Comment: `OCI_ASSOC` et al are constants; use them without the quotes, ie `db_single_select($conn, $select, $table_name, $condition, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding what [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) actually are.  In the specific case of `OCI_ASSOC` (and other [OCI constants](http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.constants.php)) it represents a simple integer value.  This can be demonstrated by the output of `var_dump(OCI_ASSOC);` which is `int(1)`.  Combining constants such as `OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS` is a simple addition operation with the result of `int(5)`.

To make your function work you should simply pass the constants directly by removing the surrounding apostrophes:

```
db_single_select($conn, $select, $table_name, $condition, OCI_ASSOC);
```

***SECURITY WARNING:***

Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (also see what the [PHP manual says about it](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)).  You should use [parameter binding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php) to mitigate the attack possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. About the SQL Injection, good point but this is an internal function and the input is not coming from user.

Answer (score -1):

You have to be sure if the connection is succeeded or not.
check the return if it's *resource* value of `$conn` in your code.

wish this help you.